# MySql PDO - Referring two colowns and displaying the id as result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been checking for more than an hour but i cant get the result, my question is, by checking two columns it must display the other columns value as result using PDO.

```
$sql ="SELECT column3 FROM tablename WHERE column1 = :request AND column2= :recived";
$conn = $conn->prepare($sql);
$fetch = $conn->execute(array(':request'=> $value1,':recived'=>$value2));
$fetch = $fetch->fetchColumn();
```

please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Don't reuse variables like that? After you prepare the statement, you can no longer use that database connection any more because you overwrote the `$conn` variable.

Comment: when i echo out no result

Comment: Make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` enabled. The last statement should have reported an error.

Comment: can you refer me any example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`execute()` returns a boolean and you're trying to call `fetchColumn()` on it. Call `fetchColumn()` on the statement instead:

```
$fetch = $conn->fetchColumn();
```

For future debugging, check your error log because there will be a message indicating the problem here.

Comment: but when i echo no result

Answer (score 1):

This is what you looking for :

```
<?php

$sql ="SELECT column3 FROM tablename WHERE column1 = :request AND column2= :recived";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':request'=> $value1,':recived'=>$value2));
$fetch = $stmt->fetchColumn();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it as such:

```
$sql ="SELECT column3 FROM tablename WHERE column1 = :request AND column2= :recived";
$conn = $conn->prepare($sql);
$conn->execute(array(':request'=> $value1,':recived'=>$value2));
$fetch = $conn ->fetchColumn();
```

You should call fetchColumn() on the statement. Because execute() only returns a boolean as result.